# Codeigniter autoload model from inside a folder

Tags: codeigniter

I want make my model named Admin.php autoload, i know how to make a model autoload, but my problem is i want to keep admin.php model class file inside a admin folder (Models/admin)

is this possible to keep model class file inside folder ?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On config/autoload.php https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html

```
$autoload['model'] = array('admin_model');
// you can use subfolders inside the model folder like
$autoload['model'] = array('admin/admin_model');
```

It is best to name the model like Admin_model.php just in case you have a controller named Admin.php

Or on controller The loading of model https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model

```
$this->load->model('admin_model');
// you can use subfolders inside the model folder like
$this->load->model('admin/admin_model');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer
I did check as you said first scenario but it returning an array, and also i made composer_autoload TRUE on config file

Comment: Show use some of your model code and controller code where you load it you can re edit you question

Comment: Thank you,
 its working now, issue was my model file name was codeigniter reserved words

Answer (score 0):

> is this possible to keep model class file inside folder ?

I think it's possible with

```
$this->load->model('admin/yourmodel');
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, yes it will work in this way, but i want to make it autoload so it would make more efficient